# How to georectify a fictive earth to a projection-less version

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a picture of a **fictive** earth-like world. Now I would like to draw the outlines and then georectify this to a projection-less version. I really need the map unrectified. Because I want to rectify it on my own.

Is that possible and even in QGIS?

Comment: So it's currently a "flat" map (rectangle)? Pick a cylindrical projection you like and georeference to it. Then you can unproject to a geographic coordinate reference system (aka WGS84 / latitude-longitude) and project it to whatever you wish.

Comment: No I have a earth round circle with the map on it, and that's all. And from this I would like to generate a rectangle. The other way around is easy indeed.

Comment: Ah, is it supposed to represent a hemisphere or the whole world? If a hemisphere, try a planar projection like Orthographic. If it's a whole world, stereographic shows 3/4ths of the world.

Comment: Otherwise, I think I need a picture!

Comment: Let's take this map e.g. http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20060724044230/lotr/images/8/83/Arda.png how would you import it. Open picture as raster image in QGIS. Which projection you use? And which are the following steps. Drawing the outline and then georectify it with some algorithm?

Comment: It looks like Mollweide. That is, the shape of the picture you liked to is very close to the earth when it's projected into a Mollweide projection. Maybe create a grid of mollweide coordinates that you can use to georeference the fictional map world. I don't know QGIS, so can't really tell you what tools to use there.

Comment: Mollweide is like what?